# Plsql procedure and exception

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Write a PL/SQL procedure: when somebody enters a number, it'll print that number. Otherwise, it'll display error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try to convert your input string to a number, and then catch the potential conversion error

```
Create Or Replace Procedure is_number(p_num varchar2) Is
  v_num Number;
Begin
  v_num := to_number(p_num);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_num);
Exception
  When VALUE_ERROR Then
    dbms_output.put_line(p_num || ' is not a number');
End is_number;
```

Comment: execute is_number(1a); error:-Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1... but user deined error msg isnot coming

Comment: Try: execute is_number('1a');

Answer (score 0):

Not too smart, but will get you started.

Using regular expressions (REGEXP_LIKE), check whether value is a number, consisting of

- any number of digits [0-9]+
- optionally |
- followed by a decimal point . (backslash is here to escape it, as dot represents any character in a regular expression)
- followed by any number of digits [0-9]+
- ^ and $ are *anchors* for beginning and end of entered value (i.e. it must begin and end with a digit)

Here it is:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_input in varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    if regexp_like(par_input, '^[0-9]+|(\.[0-9]+)$') then
  5       dbms_output.put_line(par_input);
  6    else
  7       dbms_output.put_line('Error');
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    p_test('2');
  3    p_test('2.13');
  4    p_test('x');
  5    p_test('&#');
  6  end;
  7  /
2
2.13
Error
Error

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('&number'+0);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error');
END;
/
```